# what is the different between "service ntp status" and "systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service"

Tags: 18.04, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

I have two VM, one is the server NTP for the another, for synchronization.

In my code from Ubuntu 14 I work's with NTP service, now i need to upgrade my software to Ubuntu 18 and need to know how to work with NTP on my VM.

Now i see that on Ubuntu 18 new service created `systemd-timesyncd`

I need to know if i should work with both services or only with `systemd-timesyncd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you switch from 14.04 to 18.04 two related changes happened.

- the component to provide NTP server was [changed from ntpd to chrony](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Chrony)
- systemd-timesyncd is a default available and active NTP *client*

You'll find more details, FAQs and such in the link that I added (the 18.04 release notes) above.

To summarize:

- if you have used `ntpd` as NTP server convert it to `chrony`
- if you have used NTP clients like `ntpdate` now instead use

  - `systemd-timesyncd` as it is sufficient in most cases
  - you can use `chrony` as a NTP client if you need a more sophisticated NTP client

P.S. ntpd/ntpdate still are available and work, they just aren't fully supported anymore.